# Extract value of div element which isn't an ID or a CLASS with XPATH

Tags: xpath, data-extraction

I would like to extract the info of "data-history-node-id" of this kind of code :

```
<div data-history-node-id="1001" role="article" about="/url-article" typeof="schema:Article" class="main-content">'
```

here it would be **1001**

I know how to select an ID or a CLASS but that, no...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these xpath expressions:

```
/div/@data-history-node-id
```

or

```
/div/data(@data-history-node-id)
```

Depending on your implementation, at least one should output `1001`.